# How to return distinct data to DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am retrieving data in dropdownlist from controller.

Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetDivision()
        {
            var division = db.Depts.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Division);
            return Json(division);
        }
```

I am getting duplicate values in dropdown, i need to show only only.
for example i have division - "CORPORATE AFFAIRS". I have same name multiple time, but in dropdown i need to show only one.

Comment: Depending on what your data type actually is, [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) usually works.

Comment: how can i use distinct in my code?

Comment: Without seeing the structure of the data type returned by db.Depts, that's going to be hard to answer. Most likely you need to implement an IEqualityComparer for your type (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx), otherwise LINQ just uses the default comparison (which I assume is comparing the default hashcodes).

Comment: What does the [logged SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
db.Depts.GroupBy(x => x.Division).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: i have used the same code, but i am still geting duplicates value in my dropdown

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that Depts has other attributes, so what you need is to filter only by one of them, in this case Division. db.Depts.GroupBy(x => x.Division).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList(); should work.

Comment: var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.Division == Id)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Designation); can  someone tell me how me i can delete duplicated from this lambda expression i have some same values